# Render live path in MapKit in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, mapkit

I want to draw over a map while walking on the street to record my path in SwiftUI.

I have a locationManager:

```
class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
    @Published var knownLocations: [CLLocation] = []
    @Published var location: CLLocation?
    @Published var placemark: CLPlacemark?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func geoCode(with location: CLLocation) {
        geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemark, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                self.placemark = placemark?.first
            }
        }
    }
}

extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.first else { return }
        knownLocations.append(location)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.location = location
            self.geoCode(with: location)
        }

    }
}
```

That contains an array of knownLocations, every time I move the `didUpdateLocations` is triggered correctly and saves the coordinates into the array.

My `ContentView` looks like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var locationManager: LocationManager = LocationManager()

    var body: some View {
        MapView(knowLocations: locationManager.knownLocations)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

    }
}
```

Which works fine, every time a new coordinate is added, this is called and it creates a new `MapView` with the added coordinate.

And finally, this is how my `MapView` looks:

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let mapView = MKMapView()
    let knowLocations: [CLLocation]

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MapView>) -> MKMapView {
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        addOverlays()
        return mapView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ view: MKMapView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MapView>) {
        addOverlays()
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
    }

    private func addOverlays() {
        let p = MKPolygon(coordinates: knowLocations.map({$0.coordinate}), count: knowLocations.count)
        mapView.addOverlay(p)
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
        var parent: MapView
        init(_ parent: MapView) {
            self.parent = parent
            super.init()
        }

        func mapView(_: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
            let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            renderer.fillColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
            renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
            return renderer
        }
    }
}
```

When a new `MapView` is created with the array, it calls `addOverlays()` which creates a polygon with all the coordinates. I have checked and until here it's all correctly. The first time `addOverlays()` its called, the `renderFor overlay` is also called correctly but after that it stops being called. This means that no path is created. If I mocked `knowLocations` and at the beginning it contains some fake locations, the path is drawed correctly.

What am I doing wrong? Can I only call `renderFor overlay` once? Should I just do it every X minutes rather than live?

Answer (score 0):

```
func updateUIView(_ view: MKMapView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MapView>) {
    //addOverlays()
    let p = MKPolygon(coordinates: knowLocations.map({$0.coordinate}), count: knowLocations.count)
    
    view.addOverlay(p)
    view.delegate = context.coordinator
}
```